# Java - Iterate over a 2-dimensional array starting with the middle

Tags: java, arrays

I have this totally normal loop over a 2 dimensional array.

```
for(int i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; i<array.length; j++){
        array[i][j].doSomething();
    }
}
```

I want to go through this 2 dimensional array, starting in the middle. For example, if the array has a length of 100 for both dimensions, I want it to go over it like this:

```
array[50][50] //middle of array
array[49][50] //x-1
array[50][49] //y-1
array[51][50] //x+1
array[50][51] //y+1
array[48][50] //x-2
array[49][49] //x-1 and y-1
array[50][48] //y-2
array[51][49] //x+1 and y-1
array[52][50] //x+2
array[51][51] //x+1 and y+1
array[50][52] //y+2
array[49][51] //x-1 and y+1
etc.
```

I've been spending hours on finding an efficient way and finding a solution on the internet, but I haven't found a great answer yet. Anyone who knows how to do this?

Comment: Is the array quadratic in size?

Comment: Try using a size of 5 or 6 and draw the array as a grid on a piece of paper, then write in each box the number of its printing, in the center start from 0 and try to find a pattern in the numbers - using two for-loops as you currently show will not get you anywhere unfortunately.

Comment: Already did that. The numbers I wrote in comment in my question are the coordinates they have on my grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic looop is as follows -

```
K=1;
while(true) {
    k=K-1;
    for(n=0; n<=k; n++)
      x=-k+n; y=-n;       
    for(n=1; n<=k; n++)
      x=n; y=-k+n;        
    for(n=1; n<=k; n++)
      x=k-n; y=n;         
    for(n=1; n<=k-1; n++)
      x=-n; y=k-n;
    if x out of bounds or y out of bounds continue;
    K++;
    if(K>N/2) break;
}
```

where N is the size of the array (width or height) and K is the cycle where K=1 at the center.

To find the x y coordinates you go in four loops upper left upper right .... - and since the coordinate system is located at N/2, N/2 you have to add that to x y. There are K+2(K-1)+(K-2) elements in each cycle

Answer (score 6):

*This will not yet give you any java code but rather an idea on how to approach the problem.*

Draw the grid of your array of a far smaller size on a pice of paper and draw the numbers in which the cell should get reached in each cell.

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][1][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][3][ ][ ]
[ ][2][1][4][ ]
[ ][ ][5][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

[ ][ ][8][ ][ ]
[ ][7][3][9][ ]
[6][2][1][4][A]
[ ][D][5][B][ ]
[ ][ ][C][ ][ ]

[ ][F][8][G][ ]
[E][7][3][9][H]
[6][2][1][4][A]
[L][D][5][B][I]
[ ][K][C][J][ ]

[M][F][8][G][N]
[E][7][3][9][H]
[6][2][1][4][A]
[L][D][5][B][I]
[P][K][C][J][O]
```

Clearly visible is the "snail" pattern. You always fill the outer neighbor cells of the previously filled cells.

Ignoring the outer bounds of the field the first iteration fills

> 1 cell - then
>   4 cells
>   8 cells
>   12 cells
>   ... +4 cells

In terms of loops you should not loop using `(i,j)` which both reflect indices in the array. But rather loop over the `round`s and then print the respective cells in that particular round. In round `X` you start in field `arrayLength / 2 - X`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll see if I can come up with some code :).